# How to display result in input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have written this code that takes input and calculates 2 values using javascript. but i am not able to print the result in third input field.how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {
document.form.total.value = (document.form.time.value -0) + (document.form.cost.value -0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
Timespent
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=updatesum()>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsusx/)**

Disable submitting your form:

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Your `form` name is `input`, so you must access it with it:

```
function updatesum() {
    document.input.total.value = (document.input.time.value -0) + (document.input.cost.value -0);
}
```

Also your `submit` button need quotes:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()">
```

Comment: This is not worse a separate answer, so would you please edit yours so, that conversion to number goes like `Number (document.input.time.value)` instead of subtracting zero?

Comment: @DavidJashi I've just corrected mistakes, not offerring alternatives. Your comment will add useful information to this answer. Thank you `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7utpQ/)**

Set the id attribute of your inputs like

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
Timespent
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" " id="txtTime">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" " id="txtCost">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" " id="txtTotal">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()">
</form>
```

and in your function

```
function updatesum() {
   // alert('a');
var time = document.getElementById("txtTime").value;
var cost = document.getElementById("txtCost").value;
var total=0; 
total = (time-0) +( cost-0);
   // alert(total);
document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = total;
return false;
}
```

your function should return false to prevent event

Comment: You risk getting concatenation instead of sum.